# Extracting specific elements from multiple JSON files and adding into single Excel

Tags: python, json, excel, pandas

So, basically I have two JSON files and from them I need to extract only "value" and add it to a single Excel sheet.

**JSON file 1**

```
{
 "flower": {
    "price": {
        "type": "good",
        "value": 5282.0,
        "direction": "up"
    }
   },
 "furniture": {
    "price": {
        "type": "comfy",
        "value": 9074.0,
        "direction": "down"
    }
   }
 }
```

**JSON file 2**

```
{
 "flower": {
    "price": {
        "type": "good",
        "value": 827.0,
        "direction": "up"
    }
   },
 "furniture": {
    "price": {
        "type": "comfy",
        "value": 468.0,
        "direction": "down"
    }
   }
 }
```

Now, the output should look like this in the [Excel sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ndlTr.jpg)

therefore, for solving this question here's the code so far , where JSON file 1 is json.json and file 2 is json12.json

```
import json
import pandas as pd

with open('json.json', 'r') as f: data = json.load(f)
with open('json12.json', 'r') as f: data1 = json.load(f)

data = [{'key': k, 'value1': v['price']['value']} for k, v in data.items() if k in ['flower' , 'furniture']]
print(data)
data1 = [{'key': k, 'value2': v['price']['value']} for k, v in data.items() if k in ['flower' , 'furniture']]
print(data1)

df = pd.DataFrame(data).set_index('key') 
df = pd.DataFrame(data1).set_index('key') 
df.to_excel('xcel.xlsx')
```

after running this I'm not getting the desired output...so, plz help me in this as I'm new in learning python so, it's very hard to address the correct approach..

Comment: Hey @sherkhan, did you try out my solution? I think it works. if so, please validate it

Comment: @Borja_042 if I want to add value1 and value2 and diplay in adjecent cell....can we have that kind of output, if possible?

Comment: Hello @sherkhan, for sure you can. Supposing jsons is the name of the dataframe that results from my code below you cand add values pretty easily:

jsons['valued_Added'] = jsons.value1 +  jsons.value2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this code does what you are requesting (if j1 and j2 are the jsons you are showing):

```
v1s = [j1['flower']['price']['value'], j1['furniture']['price']['value']]
v2s = [j2['flower']['price']['value'], j2['furniture']['price']['value']]
index = ['flower', 'furniture']

pd.DataFrame({'value1': v1s, 'value2': v2s, 'key': index}).set_index('key')
```